# JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists.ts(7026)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, chakra-ui

```
<Head>
        <title>Real Estate API Application</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
```

At every JSX element, I am getting this error

I tried deleting the node module and then npm install. but it didn't work, also I am using Typescrip 5 and Next 13.2 and Chakra UI

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you don't have the React types installed. I would have expected them to be installed when you installed Next.js, but you can install them directly by installing `@types/react`. For example:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/react
```

...or similar with `yarn` or your package manager of choice.

The types include the `JSX` namespace and its `IntrinsicElements` interface.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix this by restarting the TS server.

In VS Code this can be done with `CTRL+SHIFT+P + "Restart TS server" + Enter` but restarting your IDE will likely work too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your typescript and package's typescript version is mismatching.

Your locally installed typescript is 5, and your project's typescript version is maybe 4 or below.

Could you try to match your environment's typescript version and project's version?

Answer (score 0):

## Deno users: Make sure you have `deno.json` at the root of your web source

In my case, I have a core program, and from that I have auxiliary components¹: test, web app, cli app. Initially I worked on the core + cli app + test, then recently I work on the web app with Fresh. At first I separated the project to learn the framework easier. Then I joined them together so that I could debug the core easier. My code works fine when it's in a separate project; all I do is to copy it to the bigger one. Now every component has this problem:

```
JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists.deno-ts(7026)
```

Reload VS Code doesn't help.

It turns out that there must be a `deno.json` file at **the root of the web source** (not the root of your project). Even using `deno.jsonc` won't work. The file also have to have at least these line:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "preact"
  },
  "imports": {
    "preact/": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2/"
  }
```

So if you [change the source directory](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/examples/changing-the-src-dir), then there should be two `deno.json` file, one in the root of your project, and one in the root of the web source.

Read more: [Configuring JSX in Deno | Deno Docs](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/advanced/jsx_dom/jsx)

[Issue on denoland/deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/20582)

¹ "component" in here is a term of [The C4 model for visualising software architecture](https://c4model.com/), not a term of React.

Answer (score 0):

## Yarn Users: Make sure `node_modules` exists (Yarn PnP)

The new Yarn PnP paradigm will install modules in a different folder and thus `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` will not be found by `tsserver`.

To fix this without reverting to `node_modules`, you have to install [Yarn Editor SDKs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks) which are meant to resolve this problem for specific editors (currently Vim and VSCode).

If your editor is not listed, then install the `base` SDK and manually configure your editor's `tsserver` to run from `.yarn/sdks/typescript/bin/tsserver`.